# Python, выполнить шелл-код в отдельном процессе и получить ответ

Tags: python, shell, multiprocessing, subprocess

3дpacтвуйте, вообщем идея такова: выполнить шелл-код в отдельном процессе и получить ответ. Я уверен что данный вопрос является дубликатом, но я не могу найти код.

Я пробовал реализовать это таким образом:

```py
import subprocess, multiprocessing

def test(_command, _out_func):
    process= subprocess.Popen(_command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin= subprocess.PIPE, shell= True, close_fds=True)
    if _out_func: _out_func( _command, process.communicate()[0].decode() )

def run_command(command, out_func= None):
    process = multiprocessing.Process(target=test, args=([command, out_func]))
    process.start()

def o(command, output): print(command, ">", output, sep='')

run_command("python -c 'print(1)'", o)
#while 1: print(5)
```

Функция run_command принимает команду в качестве строки и функцию которая будет выполнена если нужно вернуть ответ от шелл-кода. Если функция вывода указана, то run_command будет ожидать ответа от шелл кода, а если функция не указана, то шелл код просто выполняется в отдельном процессе не ожидая вывода.

Проблема в том что если не указать функцию для вывода, то есть просто вызвать `run_command("echo 1")`, то выходит ошибка

```
sh: write error: Broken pipe

[Program finished]
```

Я понимаю что она связана с тем что основной процесс завершился, а `subprocess.Popen` пытается вернуть ответ в несуществующий процесс. Это и есть место на котором я застрял.

Как можно выполнить шелл-код и получить ответ, игнорируя `BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe`?

Answer (score 0):

```
import subprocess, threading

def test(*command):
    with subprocess.Popen(command, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True) as proc:
        yield from proc.stdout

def run_command(*command, out_func=None):
    gen = test(*command)
    if out_func:
        return out_func(command, gen)
    else:
        def _out():
            for _ in gen: continue
            print(f'воход из потока {command}')
        threading.Thread(target=_out, daemon=False).start()

def out(command, output):
    print(command)
    for chunk in output:
        print(chunk.decode('cp866', 'ignore'))

run_command('python', '-c', 'print(1)', out_func=out)
run_command('echo', '1', out_func=out)
run_command('ping', '127.0.0.1')
print("выход из __main__, до завершения run_command('ping', '127.0.0.1')")
```

out:

```
('python', '-c', 'print(1)')
1

('echo', '1')
1

выход из __main__, до завершения run_command('ping', '127.0.0.1')
воход из потока ('ping', '127.0.0.1')
```

Comment: Странно. Я запустил ваш код, но он работает совсем иначе, выводится только `('python', '-c', 'print(1)')`, а дальше пустота